# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::editObject update datacenters

Tags: image, edit, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The createFromExternalSource method does not allow you to specify a list of datacenters to enable the image to be used. I can get the image imported, but then when I then go to edit the image template to augment the datacenters, I always get:

> {"error":"Object does not exist to execute method on.
>   (SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::editObject)","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}

Does anyone have a proper example of using editObject for SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group using JSON not XMLRPC like the slcli does?

Preferred if some has a curl example which updates attributes on SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group object would be awesome.

Comment: One mistake, but still no success in updating an image template's datacenters..

i.e. image ID '12345'

url = 'https://[username]:[api_key]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/12345.json'

data body: '{ "parameters": [ { "datacenters": ["dal05", "dal09"] } ] }'

Make a PUT request with the above URL and the body and you get a 200 OK with the resultant body text 'true', but datacenters never update on the image.

Anyone know what API call the Portal makes to update an image template to add datacenters where you can launch the image?

Answer (score 0):

To update the datacenters of an image template you have to use the method “setAvailableLocations” of the service SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group.

The method editObject just edit an image template group's name and note.

You can use this curl example to update the datacenters of an imagen template:

```
curl -d @post.json -k https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/1722867/setAvailableLocations.json | python -mjson.tool
```

You have to add in this curl example the json file “@post.json”, where is the image template body.

The json file must contain the following data:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    [
                {
                                "id": 265592
                },
                {
                                "id": 814994
                },
                {
                                "id": 138124
                },
                {
                                "id": 154820
                },
                {
                                "id": 449600
                }
                ]
  ]
}
```

To get the datacenters ids you can use this curl command example:

```
curl -k "https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters.json" | python -mjson.tool
```